# Getting line number from the joinPoint

Tags: logging, wrapper, aspectj, spring-aop

I am  trying to access the line number (for logging purpose) from the joinpoint Sourcelocation in my around advice.
But it is giving

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint$SourceLocationImpl.getLine(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:282)
```

I am getting null for `loc.getLine()` on debugging.

```java
@Around("execution (* com.logger.rms.*.*(..))")
public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint procJoinpoint) throws Throwable {
  StaticPart part = (procJoinpoint.getStaticPart());
  org.aspectj.lang.reflect.SourceLocation loc = part.getSourceLocation();
  int line = loc.getLine();
  System.out.println(line);

  try {
    procJoinpoint.proceed();
  } catch (Throwable e) {
    System.out.println("checking " + procJoinpoint.getSourceLocation().getWithinType().getCanonicalName());
    String str = "Aspect ConcreteTester :" + procJoinpoint.getStaticPart().getSourceLocation().getLine();
    throw new BusinessLogicException("Throwing Custom business exception from around");
  } finally {
  }
}
```

Comment: I've the same problem, has anyone solved it?!

Comment: @maurocchi , were you able to try the below solution.

Answer (score 3):

It never worked, see source [code here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/13f23dc32ba0f17cc6d26e068c09e0b2578c6ffc/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/aspectj/MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java#L314)

```
private class SourceLocationImpl implements SourceLocation {

    ...

    @Override
    public String getFileName() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public int getLine() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

**procJoinpoint.getSourceLocation().getLine()**

```
@Around("execution (* com.logger.rms.*.*(..))")

      public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint procJoinpoint) throws Throwable {

       int line= procJoinpoint.getSourceLocation().getLine();

        System.out.println(line);

    System.out.println("in around before " + procJoinpoint );
    Object result=null;
        try {
         result = procJoinpoint.proceed();

        } catch (Throwable e) {

            throw new BusinessLogicException("Throwing Custom business exception from around");

        }finally{
            }
System.out.println("in around after " + procJoinpoint+ " wtirh result is "
                + result);
     return result
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a limitation of Spring AOP. As *deFreitas* showed, it was never implemented there. The solution is to use [AspectJ via LTW](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) instead of Spring AOP, then it works like this:

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Application().doSomething();
    new Application().doSomethingElse();
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Doing something");
  }

  private void doSomethingElse() {
    System.out.println("Doing something else");
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.SourceLocation;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Before("execution(* *())")
  public void interceptCalls(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    SourceLocation sourceLocation = thisJoinPoint.getSourceLocation();
    System.out.println("  " + sourceLocation.getWithinType());
    System.out.println("  " + sourceLocation.getFileName());
    System.out.println("  " + sourceLocation.getLine());
  }
}
```

BTW, `getColumn()` is marked as deprecated and should not be used. It yields a return value of -1 anyway. I think the method never made sense in the first place in an AOP context.

**Console log:**

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomething())
  class de.scrum_master.app.Application
  Application.java
  9
Doing something
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.doSomethingElse())
  class de.scrum_master.app.Application
  Application.java
  13
Doing something else
```